# Multiple or Chained "not equals" notation

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

I was reading on Levi–Civita symbol in a text book and it mentioned:

$\epsilon_{ijk}$ = 0 unless $i \neq j \neq k$

Does this mean the value is 0 whenever:
1. all three are equal to each other only (but it doesn't cover the case when any pair is equal to each other and the third is a different value)
or
2. any two of them are equal to each other (which also covers the case when all 3 are equal to each other)

Also a break down of the logic would also be helpful in the response so there is no confusion

BTW, is there a resource to understand these types of scenarios?  A simple notation lookup doesn't really help

Comment: By definition $\epsilon_{ijk} \neq 0$ iff $i$, $j$, and $k$ are pairwise distinct, so (2) is correct. And it is unfortunate notation.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. Is there a formal definition of this notation somewhere or is there a logical argument (truth table perhaps)? is the notation context dependent or well know?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions.